# Spring Security + JWT authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-rest

In order to protect my Rest API endpoints, I implemented Spring Security using JWT authentication. My code "works" without any issues/exceptions but it would be great if I could get my implementation validated to ensure it is implemented as expected.

`WebSecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final CustomAuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager;
    private final AuthTokenFilter authTokenFilter;
    private final AuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint;
    @Value("${api.prefix}")
    private String apiPrefix;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(null).and()
                .authenticationManager(customAuthenticationManager)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(apiPrefix + "/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(apiPrefix + "/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling(
                        httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer -> httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer
                                .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
                );
        http.addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

`AuthTokenFilter.java`

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    private final UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String jwt = parseJwt(request);

        if (Objects.isNull(jwt)) {
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Unable to extract JWT token from authentication header");
        }

        try {
            if (jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDAO.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(userDetails, null, new ArrayList<>()); // please check this line
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new CustomRTException("Error while validating jwt token", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

`CustomAuthenticationManager.java`

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    private final UserDAO userDAO;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDAO.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
        if (passwordEncoder().matches(authentication.getCredentials().toString(), userDetails.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong Password");
        }
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword());
    }
}
```

(If any other classes such as `UserDAO` or `AuthEntryPoint` is required, let me know. I just shared the classes that I thought were relevant since others were fairly straightforward)

One of the biggest issues that I had was, in `AuthTokenFilter` even after validating the JWT token, Spring tries to call `CustomAuthenticationManager#authenticate` again which caused a `NullPointerException` at this line

```
authentication.getCredentials().toString() // credentials is null because after parsing the JWT token, I am unable to get the password
```

This issue was fixed in this line

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(userDetails, null, new ArrayList<>());
```

(authorities is empty list as I am currently do not need to grant any)

This code was pieced together following some migration guides from the now deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` therefore I just want to make sure everything is correct.

Comment: Please state the reson for not using rhe built in JWT filter that exists in spring security as writing custom security solutions is bad practice. Please read the jwt chapter in the docs

Comment: @Toerktumlare can you please link the reading material for this?

Comment: You didn’t answer my question

Comment: @Toerktumlare I was following some (deprecated) guides and most of them implemented custom filters so I did the same. No other special reason, really

Comment: Why havn’t you read the official docs?

Comment: @Toerktumlare tried reading but slightly cramped for time so followed some guides I found on other sites then used some migration guides to remove the deprecated classes etc. Can you please send some reference regarding the JWT Filter you mentioned? Would be a big help

Comment: I did go through the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/) to find something regarding a JWT Filter you mentioned. Even searched for JWT but only thing that returned was regarding "OAuth 2.0 Resource Server JWT" which I don't think is applicable here. Once again, I am asking for any reference you could provide as it would be a big help. I am just trying to learn the right way to do it

Comment: why dont you think its applicable here, i want to hear your reasoning for it?

Comment: @Toerktumlare because I read through it and there was nothing regarding a class called `JWTFilter`. It mentioned an "authentication Filter" but the link to it was broken and I couldnt find a mention of it anywhere else so I assumed it was not important

Comment: You dont need acceess to a JWTFilter, all you need access to is to configure the JWTFilter to your liking. The text explains to you, how to configure the internal JWTFilter so that it validates your tokens using Nimbus (the jwt library that comes with spring security)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246925/discussion-between-toerktumlare-and-user9492428).

Comment: I would have liked to know how this conversation played out

Comment: Do you have a github repo of your implementation of JWT? Because I am also like you and many other, I cannot find anything concrete from spring documentation without the mentioning of OAuth2 and OpenID Connect @user9492428